# postmaster dead but pid file exists following "pg_ctl start"

Tags: postgresql

i am using postgres 9.2 on redhat 6

i'm a little confused as to why the following is happening with postgres

1. when postgres is running, performing "service postgresql92-postgresql status" as root results in "postmaster (pid  1379) is running..." (as expected)
2. as postgres run "pg_ctl stop -D $PGDATA -m s" to stop postgres
3. as postgres run "pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start" to start postgres (postgres is now running correctly)
4. now as root run "service postgresql92-postgresql status", output is now "postmaster dead but pid file exists"

my confusion is why am i getting the message in step 4 when postgres is running correctly? am i stopping/starting postgres incorrectly?

thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

this has been answered for me over at dba.stackexchange, this thread explains whats was going on

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98117/postmaster-dead-but-pid-file-exists/98122#98122